# "No such file or directory" error when using "gcloud compute scp" command in SSH window to upload file to vm instance

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I keep getting the error as described when using the following command in an SSH window (opened after hitting the "SSH" button on my instance "test-gpu"):

```
jiatongjiangsherry97@test-gpu:~$ gcloud compute scp 
/C:/Users/LENOVO/Downloads/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.3.1.20.tgz 
jiatongjiangsherry97@test-gpu:~/
```

After I answered "Y" to the following question:

```
Did you mean zone [us-west1-b] for instance: [test-gpu] (Y/n)?  Y
```

It shows:

```
/C:/Users/LENOVO/Downloads/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.3.1.20.tgz: No such file 
or directory
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].
```

But I checked several times that this is the exact directory and file name.

On a side note: I also tried typing all these in a cloud shell window instead of the SSH. And then it returned "Insufficient permission", although I have logged in to my service account. (If this piece of info helps.)

Anyone has any idea why it says "No such file or directory"?

Thanks in advance.

Jiatong

Comment: where does `C:/Users/LENOVO/Downloads/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.3.1.20.tgz` actually exist? On your compute instance, your cloud shell instance or on your local machine?

Comment: It's a zip file on my C drive, so on my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're trying to copy `C:/Users/LENOVO/Downloads/cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.3.1.20.tgz` which is a file on your local machine then you need to run the `gcloud compute scp` on your local machine.

Running the command in the window open by the `SSH` instance button runs it on your compute instance and running it in the cloud shell runs it on the cloud shell instance. Neither of those instances has access to your local machine - hence the  `No such file or directory` error.

Note that you'll probably need to adjust the command to the local machine OS (apparently Windows) since referencing files is done differently.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried on my local machine terminal initially, but it showed "'gcloud' is not an internal or external command, executable program or batch file."

Comment: You need the Google Cloud SDK installed on the local machine and `gcloud` in your path (or executed with full path)

Comment: And also I followed this article:  https://medium.com/searce/installing-tensorflow-gpu-with-nvidia-cuda-on-a-google-cloud-platform-vm-instance-b059ea47e55c       which does exactly the same thing as what I'm trying to do. I think her 3rd step (along with the rest of her codes are probably written in SSH).

Comment: Oh i see I''ll try installing Google Cloud SDK and see if it works out

Comment: Hello, after I downloaded and set up GC SDK, logged in with my google account, and typed:                                                                   
gcloud compute scp \C:\Users\LENOVO\Downloads\cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.3.1.20.tgz jiatongjiangshery97@test-gpu:~\                                                                It initially returned a list of warnings saying no SSH key existing, will generate a key, and I continued. Then same error occurred: "No such file or directory." The next time I typed the above line, no SSH warning but still the same No File error...

Comment: OK, that mean eventually you got `gcloud` to start. Now the error comes from the `.tgz` file. I still suspect you aren't specifying it correctly, but I don't have a windows machine to check. Can you do a `dir \C:\Users\LENOVO\Downloads\cudnn-9.0-linux-x64-v7.3.1.20.tgz`? From what I remember it didn't need a `\\` prefix.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't need a \ prefix. It works after I deleted it! Problems like this are stupid but really frustrating and it's a relief to have people here to help. Thanks!

Comment: OMG. What a stupid mistake I made. Now it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: OMG. What a stupid mistake I made. Now it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You may consider transferring files using WinSCP. All needed detail is found in the "Transferring files using WinSCP on Windows workstations" [sub-chapter](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#winscp) of the "Transferring Files to Instances" online document.